# Specifying the ith index of an array while leaving other indices blank

Tags: r, indexing, subset

I am basically trying to specify one index (or two) of an n-dimensional array at a time (leaving all other indices blank), where both the position of the index/indices being specified and the dimensionality of the array are parameters in my code (i.e. i need this to work for any n-dimensional array where n>1).

I have an array (H) of dimensions 2x2x...x2 (n dimensions, each with index range 1 thru 2). n is not specified, just restricted to n>1.
I have another array (J) of dimensions nx2x2x...x2 (n+1 total dimensions, where the first dimension has index range 1 thru n and the others have index ranges 1 thru 2).
I am trying to use a for-loop to define the following subsets of the array (assuming here that n=4):

```
J[1,1,,,]<-H[1,,,]
J[1,2,,,]<-H[1,,,]
J[2,,1,,]<-H[,1,,]
J[2,,2,,]<-H[,1,,]
J[3,,,1,]<-H[,,1,]
J[3,,,2,]<-H[,,1,]
J[4,,,,1]<-H[,,,1]
J[4,,,,2]<-H[,,,1]
```

I've been doing this by looping through i=1 to i=n and trying to define the relevant subsets of J for each value of i. However, for this to work, I need a way to indicate an arbitrary number of "blank" indices. 
For fixed n and fixed i this is straightforward - you can simply leave indices blank, as shown above, or substitute TRUE:

```
J[1,1,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE] 
#is equivalent to 
J[1,1,,,]
```

To make this work for an array of dimensionality n I initially tried creating an one-row index matrix consisting of numbers and 'TRUE' values, but of course R coerces all the values to numeric. A list or one-row data frame allows numeric and logical entries but cannot be used to index the array. This is the problem I run into with the example code included below.

```
J<-array(NA,dim=c(n,rep(2,n)))
for(i in 1:n){
  index_j<-matrix(rep(T,n+1),nrow=1)
  index_j<-data.frame(index_j)
  index_j[c(1,i+1)]<-c(i,1)
  index_h<-index_j[2:(n+1)]
  J[index_j]<-H[index_h]
  index_j[i+1]<-2
  J[index_j]<-H[index_h]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay I've answered my own question, but rather than delete it I figure I'll post the answer in case anyone finds it useful in the future.

The solution uses the function *extract.array* (package *R.utils*) to subset arrays and the function *abind* (package *abind*) to combine arrays.

Here's the annotated code:

```
Jlist<-vector("list",n)
    for(i in 1:n){
      index<-vector("list",n) #indices for each dimension of the array
      for(j in 1:n){
        if(j==i){index[[j]]<-1}else{index[[j]]<-1:2}
      } 
#all dimensions of the array H have index range 1:2
      J_i<-extract.array(H,indices=index,drop=F) 
#extracting the subset of H with the specified indices
      Jlist[[i]]<-abind(J_i,J_i,along=i) 
#combine two copies of J_i, which has index range = 1 in dimension i, along dimension i --> result has index range 1:2 in all dimensions, just like H
    }
    J<-abind(Jlist,along=0) 
#Jlist has n entries, each an n-dimensional array with index range 1:2 in all dimensions. Use abind to combine these in a new dimension (along = 0) producing an array with n+1 dimensions where the first dimension has index range 1:n.
```